# Reducing this binomial expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need help for showing that:
$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^{50} = k \cdot(k-1)\binom{50}{k}$$

is equal to:

$$50\cdot 49\cdot 2^{48}$$
please help , thank you.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
k\times(k-1)\times\binom{50}{k}=50\times49\times\binom{48}{k-2}
$$ giving
$$
\sum\limits_{k=2}^{50} k\times(k-1)\times\binom{50}{k}=50\times49\times\sum\limits_{k=2}^{50}\binom{48}{k-2}=50\times49\times\sum\limits_{m=0}^{48}\binom{48}{m}
$$
then one may use the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: Thank you. Only now relized the equivalent in the first line you wrote and from there it's a short way.

Comment: The right hand side of your first equation needs $k-2$, not $k$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thank you very much for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a combinatorial proof:

A committee of $2 \le k \le 50$ people needs to be formed from $50$ people such that: There is exactly one president, exactly one vice president, and other members are optional. How many ways of forming such a committee?

**Method 1**:

Choosing president: $50$ ways.

Choosing vice-president $49$ ways.

All other members are optional, so $2^{48}$ ways of choosing them.

**Method 2**

On the other hand, fix the size of committee to be $2 \le k \le 50$.

Choose $k$ people from $50$: $\binom{50}{k}$ ways.

Now, out of $k$ people, choose $2$ people for president and vice president: $\binom{k}{2}$ ways.

Choose president and vice president from the $2$ people: 2 ways.

So total ways for fixed $k$: $\binom{50}{k}k (k-1)$.

Now sum this over all possible values of $k$ to get the quantity in the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{50}$, and differentiate this twice, then substitute the value of $x=1$. The result follows immediately.